# what is correct javascript for displaying counter in for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have always echoed loop incremented variables by using php. Now I want to use the simpler pure javascript.

instead of this:

```
<script>

<?php

echo "<script>";

for ($i = 1; $i <= 48; $i++) {

echo 'X'.$i;   

echo '}';

echo "</script>";

?>
```

I just want this:

```
<script>

for (i = 1; i <= 48; i++) {

document.write (X[i]); //What is the correct syntax for this?

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your desired O/P. Concat using '+'.

```js
    
function hello() 
{ 
    for (i = 1; i <= 48; i++) 
    {   document.write ('X'+i); }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
</head>
<body onload="hello();">
</body>
</html>
```